# Laravel 5.4 pushing new object to array

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I am trying to push an object to a user model.

The user model, has the below parameter:

```
User.posts.
```

Where posts is an array.

First I tried the below:

```
$user->posts()->save($Post);
```

This didn't add the new Post object to the user.posts (but it didn't return an error).

I also tried `$user->posts()->push($Post);`

and `$user->posts = array_add($Post)`...but this is requiring three parameters.
                           
Sorry, I am new to laravel...How to push an object instance to the array (posts) of the user model?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get a copy of the posts [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections), then [push](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-push) the new post onto it, then assign the updated collection back and save.

There are cleaner ways to do this, but I am showing you this way so you can see the order of things that needs to happen:

```
$postsCollection = $user->posts();
$postsCollection->push($newPost);
$user->posts = $postsCollection;
$user->save();
```

Comment: it was giving an error first of Illegal offset type....I changed it like: 
$postsCollection = $user->posts()->get();
$postsCollection->push($newPost);
$user->posts = $postsCollection;
$user->save();
now it is saving, but as an empty array...any idea what is going wrong?